# Add a specific class to <li> elements and repeat adding pattern

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have an `<ul>` list and I'm adding different classes to each one of the elements. The jQuery is working good but what I cannot find how to do is to repeat the pattern if the list continues growing dynamically.

Example

```
<ul class="portfolio">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
var sizes = ['col-md-6', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-3', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-3'];
    $('.portfolio li').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass(sizes[index]);
});
```

The issue I'm having is that my array runs once, with this I mean that the classes will only be assigned to the first 5 `<li>` items (same number of my array) but then stops running.

Is there any way to repeat that array pattern to continue running and applying classes to the `<li>` elements as the list grows?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/x3wjrs0q/?

Comment: Hey @Sushil, that's the exact thing I was looking for! Do you mind adding it as your answer so I can mark as the solution? Thanks so much!

Comment: sure @Jaypee. m posting it now. give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `index` and `divide` it by the length of your array to get the actual index for dynamically added `li`'s

update your jquery code like this

```
$(function(){
    var sizes = ['col-md-6', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-3', 'col-md-6', 'col-md-3'];
    $('.portfolio li').each(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();

        var val = index % sizes.length; // this gives you the remainder n u can use that as an index.
        console.log('index - ' + index + ' | val - ' + val);
        $(this).addClass(sizes[val]);
    });
});
```

Here's a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x3wjrs0q/1/)**. i've given some custom colors to the li's for it to look more visible. Hope this helps